# Django BaseManager.all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Login'

Tags: python, django

I have database:

```
class Users(models.Model):
     Login = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) <--- one to one field
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name='mail')
     balance = models.IntegerField(blank=False, verbose_name='balance')
     bonus = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='count_bonus')

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.Login.username)

     class Meta:
         verbose_name = 'Users'
         verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
         ordering = ['id']
```

and i need to query the database to get all the values by request.user, but i get the error.

BaseManager.all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Login'

```
def Account(request):

    user = Users.objects.all(Login=request.user)

    context = {
        'title' : 'title',
        'user' : user,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name='site/account.html', context=context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Queryset.filter` method instead. `Queryset.all` just gives you the queryset to retrieve all the records.

```
...
user = Users.objects.filter(Login=request.user)
...
```

However, your `Users` model has a one-to-one relation to the `User`, so you can define `related_name`, for example

```
class Users(models.Model):
     Login = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="user_info", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ...
```

Then, you will be able to access related `Users` object this way

```
...
user = request.user.user_info
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply query on the `all()` method which Django doesn't allow, it is simply used to return all model objects.

What you need is to apply `filter()` on the query set. Please note that applying `filter()` on model object applies to `all` objects by default and you don't need to explicitly use `all()`.

```
def Account(request):

  user = Users.objects.filter(Login=request.user)

  context = {
      'title' : 'title',
      'user' : user,
  }
  return render(request=request, template_name='site/account.html', context=context)
```